# Why is Contacts.app's "General" tab different on two Macs with the same software?

Tags: macos, contacts.app

I have two macs, a 2010 MBP and a 2013 MBA. They run identical software: both use macOS 10.12.6, and Contacts.app 10.0, build 1756.20.

The "General" pane of Contacts.app's Preferences displays differently on the two machines. The MBP shows this:

[image]

while the MBA shows this:

[image]

Why are the panes different?

Answer (score 1):

One Mac only has one account set up, so there is no "Default Account" option. The other Mac has multiple accounts set up, or one account and local data, thus it gives you the option of choosing a default account. What else is listed in the "Default Account" menu?

Comment: Contacts' second preference tab is "Accounts." On both macs, the "Accounts" tab shows two accounts: the iCloud account is first on the list, and is enabled; the Google account is second on the list, and the "enable" box is not checked. The lists are identical. I took a look at the "Internet Accounts" system preferences: they're identical too, and show the same three accounts on both computers.

Comment: The "Default Account" list other entry is "iCloud," But as I indicated, both Contacts are set up the same, with iCloud enabled and Google not enabled.